# question regarding equivalent circuits

Tags: power, current

I have an assignment on equivalent circuits 
I want to know the advantages of equivalent circuits. I searched alot on google but The answers were inappropriate

Kindly help me with this question

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent circuit is a simplified version of the given circuit, retaining all of the electrical characteristics of a given circuit. Equivalent circuits help in analysis of complex circuits and greatly simplify calculations.

Thévenin equivalent circuit for example is a often used in network reduction and modeling.

It states that any linear, bilateral two-terminal circuit can be replaced by a single voltage source and a series impedance. The equivalent circuit would retain the same properties as mentioned above.

Here is an example:

[image]

The circuit in (d) is the simplified equivalent of (a).